# Filter duplicates when editing rebase/squash commit message

Tags: git

Trying to solve a minor annoyance. *Minor*, I know...

I often rebase to reorder and then squash related commits. To keep my own sanity while doing so I try to give related commits the same commit message, like so:

```
1 pick e5e2ba2b Message 1
2 pick 6ad71924 Message 2
3 s f853008e Message 2
4 pick 0a04db83 Message 3
5 
6 # Rebase d0b1a378..0a04db83 onto d0b1a378 (4 commands)
7 #
8 # Commands:
...
```

For the squashed commit of `6ad71924`/`f853008e` Git will popup the editor again (fine), with each commit message put into the proposed message, despite these being literally the same commit messages (ugh). Is there a way to not see the duplicated commit messages? Maybe I can add some hook to filter the commit messages before the editor pops up?

Comment: You can replace `pick` with `f` (instead of `s`), and the editor won't show, it will automatically take the other commit's message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: By using "fixup" instead of "squash", the commit's message is discarded.

From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> If you want to fold two or more commits into one, replace the command "pick" for the second and subsequent commits with "squash" or "fixup". If the commits had different authors, the folded commit will be attributed to the author of the first commit. The suggested commit message for the folded commit is the concatenation of the commit messages of the first commit and of those with the "squash" command, but omits the commit messages of commits with the "fixup" command.

Comment: Note to self: _duh_. Thank you!